Why does automatic weights create twisting?
I am really confused by this- when I apply automatic weights for this hand, the weighting is spread incorrectly, and way too far across the mesh for each bone. The effect is that when I attempt to bend one finger, the whole hand starts to twist and stretch! The odd thing is that when I made a new hand, and applied another armature, the auto weights worked normally and only affected their local digits. I want to understand what I'm doing to create a mesh that has this problem, since I don't want to have to constantly remake them until they work! I've included the problem mesh below.




In this case, I want the auto weighted bones to only affect the mesh areas they're directly within, so the fingers/ thumbs, opposed to this weird global spread. If anyone would have any advice for what I'm doing wrong, I'd be super appreciative.

Have you checked that the Normals are correct on that hand? - In Edit mode, select All then Shift-N to recalculate the normals. You can also check them by checking Face Orientation on the Overlays menu. - Should all be blue.

Unfortunately yes, they're all blue but the problem is still there.

You'll need to share your Blend file in that case so that we can see what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.
